# php/yii logging: categories not working

Tags: php, logging, yii

in my controller:

```
private $log_category   = "application.event";
private $log_info           = "info";
```

then I log like this (in the same controller):

```
Yii::trace("actionIndex", $log_category);
Yii::log("saved",$log_info,$log_category);
```

but it doesn't work: the logs don't appear in the log file.
Here's the config:

```
'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error,warning,info,trace',
                    'categories' => 'application'
                ),
            ),
```

neither `"*"` nor `"application.*"` works; but if I remove the categories parameter altogether (or put it to empty), I get system messages in the log - this means the log file is being written and that somehow my categories are wrong.

How to define the category?

Comment: $this->log_category and $this->log_info ??

Comment: blush....my php skills are plainly visible here...

Comment: Well, glad to help. I just thought that would raise an error, but from your question it didn't seem like that. I will provide an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missing a `$this` when calling your class properties:

```
Yii::trace("actionIndex", $this->log_category);
Yii::log("saved",$this->log_info,$this->log_category);
```